# Python: Loop a variable for a simple OLS

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, regression

I am looking to build a function in Python which creates a simple OLS regression with the following equation:

```
 Y_i - Y_i-1 = A + B(X_i - X_i-1) + E
```

In words, Y_Lag = alpha + beta(X_Lag) + Error term

Currently, I have the following dataset (This is a short version)

Note: Y = Historic_Rate

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)), columns=['Historic_Rate', 'Overnight', '1M', '3M', '6M'])
```

So, what I'm trying to build is that I iteratively take an X variable and put it into a simple linear regression, the code I have built so far looks like this:

```
#Start the iteration process for the regression to in turn fit 1 parameter

#Import required packages 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

#Import dataset

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)), columns=['Historic_Rate', 'Overnight', '1M', '3M', '6M'])
#Y_Lag is always 1 time period only

df['Y_Lag'] = df['Historic_Rate'].shift(1)

#Begin the process with 1 lag, taking one x variable in turn

array = df[0:0]
array.drop(array.columns[[0,5]], axis=1, inplace=True)
for X in array:
    df['X_Lag'] = df['X'].shift(1)
    Model = df[df.columns[4:5]]
    Y = Model['Y_Lag']
    X = Model['X_Lag']

    Reg_model = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
    predictions = model.predict(X) 
    # make the predictions by the model

    # Print out the statistics
    model.summary()
```

So, in essence, I'm looking to create a list of the column headers, which, in turn, will systematically go through my loop and each variable will be lagged and then regressed against a lagged Y variable.

I'd also appreciate knowledge of how to output a model.X where X is the Xth iteration of the array, for a dynamic naming of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, I think you are just confusing your variable `X` with the string `'X'` within your loop. I also think you aren't calculating `Y_i - Y_i-1`, and are instead just regressing `Y_i-1` against `X_i-1`.

Here's how you would loop through the regressions. We'll also use a dictionary to store the regression results, with the keys as the column names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)), 
                  columns=['Historic_Rate', 'Overnight', '1M', '3M', '6M'])

fit_d = {}  # This will hold all of the fit results and summaries
for col in [x for x in df.columns if x != 'Historic_Rate']:
    Y = df['Historic_Rate'] - df['Historic_Rate'].shift(1)
    # Need to remove the NaN for fit
    Y = Y[Y.notnull()]

    X = df[col] - df[col].shift(1)
    X = X[X.notnull()]

    X = sm.add_constant(X)  # Add a constant to the fit

    fit_d[col] = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
```

Now if you wanted to make some predictions, say for your last model, you could just do:

```
fit_d['6M'].predict(sm.add_constant(df['6M']-df['6M'].shift(1)))
#0    NaN
#1    0.5
#2   -2.0
#3   -1.0
#4   -0.5
#dtype: float64
```

And you can get the summaries: `fit_d['6M'].summary()`

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:          Historic_Rate   R-squared:                       0.101
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.348
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.2254
Date:                Thu, 27 Sep 2018   Prob (F-statistic):              0.682
Time:                        11:27:33   Log-Likelihood:                -9.6826
No. Observations:                   4   AIC:                             23.37
Df Residuals:                       2   BIC:                             22.14
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.4332      1.931     -0.224      0.843      -8.740       7.873
6M            -0.2674      0.563     -0.475      0.682      -2.691       2.156
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   2.301
Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.254
Skew:                          -0.099   Prob(JB):                        0.881
Kurtosis:                       1.781   Cond. No.                         3.44
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Huge oversight from me, I didn't even realise I wasn't taking the difference, this looks comprehensive, thank you

Comment: Yup! Also don't forget that you need to add a constant to the fit manually in `statsmodels`

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, I'm looking forward to the point where I am as familiar with the syntax as other, more basic, languages